# Last column shouldn't open a collapsible table

Tags: jquery, web, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend, frameworks

I am trying to remove the click effect of table row class from the last td of the table row, which has an action, and trying to do it using jQuery.
Here is my table:
[image]

You can see when I click on a `td` with action it shows the actions menu as well as shows the hidden table row, but I just want to show the actions menu. The rest of `td` elements should show the hidden table row when clicked.

```
<div class="table-responsive expended-table">
                                    <table id="to-do" class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                                <th class="text-left">Team Name <i class="fa fa-sort"
                                                        aria-hidden="true"></i> </th>
                                                <th class="text-left">Team Leader <i class="fa fa-sort"
                                                        aria-hidden="true"></i> </th>
                                                <th class="text-left">Geography <i class="fa fa-sort"
                                                        aria-hidden="true"></i> </th>
                                                <th>Region <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                                                <th>Type <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                                                <th>Action</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr class="border-bottom order_extra_info">
                                                
                                                <td><i class="fa fa-angle-right "></i></td>
                                                <td>U.S. East Region</td>
                                                <td class="project-people text-left"><a data-trigger="hover click"
                                                        class="popover-toggle text-primary" href="#"><img alt="image"
                                                            class="rounded-circle" src="img/a2.jpg">
                                                        <span>Simen Jhones</span></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>LATAM</td>
                                                <td>East</td>
                                                <td>Commercial</span>
                                                </td>
                                                
                                                <td id="stop-action">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
                                                        </a>
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal"
                                                                    data-target="#edit-team">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                                                    Edit Team</a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                                                    Remove Team</a>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="order_extra_infos" id="1545">
                                                <td colspan="15">
                                                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="text-left" width="25%">Name</td>
                                                                <td class="text-left" width="25%">Email</td>
                                                                <td class="text-left" width="50%">Role
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="text-left">Simen Jhones
                                                                    <br>Albert John
                                                                    <br>Brian Carter
                                                                    <br>Harriet Blu
                                                                    <br> Harry Nel
                                                                    <br>David Warner
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td class="text-left">simen.johnes@enableu.com
                                                                    <br>albert.john@enableu.com
                                                                    <br>brian.carter@enableu.com
                                                                    <br>harriet.blu@enableu.com
                                                                    <br>harry.nel@enableu.com
                                                                    <br>david.warner@enableu.com
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td class="text-left">Coach
                                                                    <br>Sales Rep
                                                                    <br>Sales Rep
                                                                    <br>Sales Rep
                                                                    <br>Coach
                                                                    <br>Coach
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                              </tbody>
                          </table>
                       </div>
```

I have tried the following way, which has no effect.

```
$(".order_extra_info").each(function() {
     $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle(".order-extra-infor-shown");
        $(this).find('td > i').toggleClass('fa-angle-right fa-angle-down');
                
       });
   });
```

How do I exclude the click handler from the last `td`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want your click handler that toggles the visibility of the second table body row to apply to all `<td>` elements in the first row *except for* the last one.

For that, I would modify the selector to which the handler is being applied to apply to `td` elements instead of the entire `tr.order_extra_info`. We can then use the [:not CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to extend our selector so that it does not match the last `<td>` element: `.order_extra_info td:not(:last-child)`.

Of course, we will need to modify the handler body now so that it gets the row element, which will be the `.parent()` of whichever `td` was clicked.

```js
$('.order_extra_info td:not(:last-child)').on('click', function () {
  const $row = $(this).parent();
  $row.next().toggle(".order-extra-infor-shown");
  $row.find('td > i').toggleClass('fa-angle-right fa-angle-down');
});
```

```css
.order_extra_info {
  background: orange;
}

.order_extra_infos {
  display: none;
}

.order-extra-infor-shown {
  display: block;
}

td i.fa {
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

td i.fa-angle-down {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive expended-table">
  <table id="to-do" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th class="text-left">Team Name <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i> </th>
        <th class="text-left">Team Leader <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i> </th>
        <th class="text-left">Geography <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i> </th>
        <th>Region <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
        <th>Type <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="border-bottom order_extra_info">

        <td><i class="fa fa-angle-right "></i></td>
        <td>U.S. East Region</td>
        <td class="project-people text-left"><a data-trigger="hover click" class="popover-toggle text-primary" href="#"><img alt="image" class="rounded-circle" src="img/a2.jpg">
            <span>Simen Jhones</span></a>
        </td>
        <td>LATAM</td>
        <td>East</td>
        <td><span>Commercial</span></td>

        <td id="stop-action">
          <div>
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="">
              <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-team">
                  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                  Edit Team</a>
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                  Remove Team</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="order_extra_infos" id="1545">
        <td colspan="15">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td class="text-left" width="25%">Name</td>
                <td class="text-left" width="25%">Email</td>
                <td class="text-left" width="50%">Role
                </td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="text-left">Simen Jhones
                  <br>Albert John
                  <br>Brian Carter
                  <br>Harriet Blu
                  <br> Harry Nel
                  <br>David Warner
                </td>
                <td class="text-left">simen.johnes@enableu.com
                  <br>albert.john@enableu.com
                  <br>brian.carter@enableu.com
                  <br>harriet.blu@enableu.com
                  <br>harry.nel@enableu.com
                  <br>david.warner@enableu.com
                </td>
                <td class="text-left">Coach
                  <br>Sales Rep
                  <br>Sales Rep
                  <br>Sales Rep
                  <br>Coach
                  <br>Coach
                </td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```